# Grunt require fails to create multiple modules as expected

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, require, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I have structure like:

- app

  - scripts

    - libs

      - jquery.js
      - bootstrap.js
      - moment.js
    - app.js
    - vendor.js
    - common.js
    - app.config.js
    - main.js #require config

Note vendor.js is just a file that includes all files under libs. Ex

`//vendor.js
define(['jquery','bootstrap', 'moment'], function(){});`

Just to list out the dependencies:

- `app.js` depends on `common.js` and `app.config.js`
- `common.js` depends on `vendor.js`
- `app.config.js` depends on `moment.js`

What I'm trying to do is run the grunt requirejs command to create a `vendor.js` file with all files under `libs/` and a `app.js` with the rest of the files not included in `vendor.js`.

Here is what my requirejs options looks like:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    'use strict';
    var config = {
        dist: {
            options: {
                appDir: 'app/',
                baseUrl: './scripts',
                mainConfigFile: 'app/scripts/main.js',
                dir: 'dist/scripts/',
                modules: [
                    { name: 'vendor'},
                    { name: 'app', exclude: ['vendor'] }
                ]
            }
        }
    };
    grunt.config('requirejs', config);
};
```

What I get from running the above is the following build.txt

```
scripts/vendor.js
----------------
scripts/libs/jquery.js
scripts/libs/bootstrap.js
scripts/libs/moment.js
scripts/app.js
scripts/vendor.js
scripts/common.js
scripts/app.config.js

scripts/app.js
----------------
```

As you can see all the files are just appended to `vendor.js` and not `app.js`. I would expect vendor.js to include `vendor.js` and its dependencies. And `app.js` to include the rest since `vendor` is excluded.

I've tried numerous combination and still a nogo here.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using grunt instead of gulp or webpack? Also, why aren't you following more commonly used structures for grunt files?

Comment: @Pytth pre-existing code, the structure I might be able to alter but I'd rather get this to work with minimal change before I update anything major. Appreciate the comment man.

Comment: Np man! is that your whole grunt file?

Comment: @Pytth For that task that's pretty much it. I was thinking maybe it was some shim dependencies causing issue but after checking it I don't think thats the cause

Comment: Just wondering, what happens if you switch all `app` and `vendor` strings in that config? Do you have a similar `app.js` file similar to the vendor one with: `define(['jquery','bootstrap', 'moment'], function(){});`

Comment: @Pytth Yea the first entry seems to be taking all the files. Even if I just have  `{ name: 'foo', create: true, include: ['lodash']},` it seems to just concat all the files

Comment: Honestly man, I have looked up the various grunt `requirejs` libs, and none seem to share that structure for their config files. Seems like you are fighting a very real up hill battle with this one by having to adhere to that structure.

Comment: @Pytth I agree. I think I found the issue( or a lead!). In the require config(not the grunt config above), there is a `deps: ['app']`. That seems to be the problem because the optimizer reads the require.config and sees app is dependencies, which just loads all files....Going from here, and if resolved, will update. Thanks for the chat, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue! The problem was with my require config file thats feed to the grunt requirejs task. The require config file had `deps: ['app']` code, which conflicted when trying to split up into modules because as soon as the require config was feed to the grunt requirejs task, it seen app as necessary dependency, which meant app and all its files were marked as dependent and thus included in the first module file listed.